# How to query screen pinning settings?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

Is there any way to programmatically query the system settings for screen pinning, i.e. whether it is turned on and whether a pin is required for unpinning apps?

Background: I would like to implement a Kiosk app which ensures that leaving the screen pinning mode requires entering the device PIN. The full-blown lock task mode with a device owner app is unfortunately not an option for me, which is why I am using the unprivileged screen pinning mode:
https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

Programmatically putting an App into screen pinning mode with `startLockTask()` is not a problem. However how can I (programmatically) ensure that the user needs to enter the PIN when leaving the screen pinning mode (without including the app in `setLockTaskPackages` and going the full-blown device owner way)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using device administrator then and use this to lock your screen on back press

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm;
dpm.resetPassword(newpin, 0);
dpm.lockNow();
```